# Android Webview doesn't show contents clearly

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In recents, i had a problem with android webview i wanted to play youtube embed video center of the screen but webview had showed me black blank area in right side of video. Now i need to open documents by using Google docs but i have same problem in documents like:

[image]

Here is my webview codes:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
            mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        }
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.CLOSE);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(-20);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
    //mWebView.loadUrl(" http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf");
    String pdf = "http://www.projectcounter.org/SSPJune_2007.ppt";
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Comment: Are you trying to load the PDF in webview ?

Comment: Yes, i have to view documents like ppt,pdf,doc or xls in android. I found this method easily.